# Can't enable python_module in apache configuration (loop)

Tags: python, macos, apache, cgi

MAMP new installation on MacBook Air BigSur 11.6.5. Just started to test things to make sure they work and ran into a loop.  I enabled ExecCGI, cgi_module, perl_module, and php_module everything works correctly.  The test cgis in the folder work.  When I try to enable python_module MAMP won't initialize and get the following entries in the apache error log. Will continue in loop until I hit STOP and turn off python_module.  How do I fix this. Obvious from the log it has something to do with enabling python.  Since I teach python it would be nice if I could demonstrate python cgis.

[Wed May 04 15:03:27.088770 2022] [:notice] [pid 8229] mod_python: Creating 32 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Wed May 04 15:03:27.089131 2022] [:notice] [pid 8229] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Wed May 04 15:03:27.146613 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8229] AH00163: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) PHP/7.4.21 OpenSSL/1.0.2u mod_python/3.5.0- Python/2.7.13 mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.30.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 04 15:03:27.146737 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00094: Command line: '/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd -f /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf'
[Wed May 04 15:03:27.160067 2022] [:notice] [pid 8443] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 8443)
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
[Wed May 04 15:03:28.229844 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00052: child pid 8448 exit signal Abort trap (6)
[Wed May 04 15:03:28.230605 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00052: child pid 8447 exit signal Abort trap (6)
[Wed May 04 15:03:28.230674 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00052: child pid 8446 exit signal Abort trap (6)
[Wed May 04 15:03:28.230706 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00052: child pid 8445 exit signal Abort trap (6)
[Wed May 04 15:03:28.230775 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00052: child pid 8444 exit signal Abort trap (6)
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
[Wed May 04 15:03:30.356584 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00052: child pid 8482 exit signal Abort trap (6)
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
[Wed May 04 15:03:31.423802 2022] [core:notice] [pid 8229] AH00052: child pid 8792 exit signal Abort trap (6)
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.